# how to properly sort product item on a single page

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, shopping-cart

so i'm new to developing an eCommerce site in general, trying this out for a personal project.

so i have my products displayed on the home page under category "all products".
[image: this is where i direct it to a single page view]

i have it "href" to my product page where it gets the item code and displays it on the single page, this works fine but.......... on that page i get a repetition of that page for every item in my database. any ideas on why i'm facing this? if i take out the * from "SELECT * FROM" i break everything :(

Comment: on the single item page, you need a where clause using the code that you have. of course it's going to repeat all 8 items.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the suggestion, however if you look at the screenshot i had provided you with, you'd observe in the php clause i had later done that "foreach($product_array as $key=>$value)".

Comment: copy past the code here. Don't use screenshots for code or logs.